# Architecture Neural Network with weights

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-trees

I would like to draw an image like this:

[image]

Except that I want the nodes to be regular black circles instead of the colours. Also I have only one output instead of two as in the picture.

In another thread I found the following architecture
[image]
Which corresponds to the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    init/.style={
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=2pt,
      font=\Huge,
      join = by -latex
    },
    squa/.style={
      draw,
      inner sep=2pt,
      font=\Large,
      join = by -latex
    },
    start chain=2,node distance=13mm
    ]
    \node[on chain=2] 
      (x2) {$z_2$};
    \node[on chain=2,join=by o-latex] 
      {$w_2$};
    \node[on chain=2,init] (sigma) 
      {$\displaystyle\Sigma$};
    \node[on chain=2,squa,label=above:{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Activate \\ function}}]   
      {$f$};
    \node[on chain=2,label=above:Output,join=by -latex] 
      {$y$};
    \begin{scope}[start chain=1]
    \node[on chain=1] at (0,1.5cm) 
      (x1) {$z_1$};
    \node[on chain=1,join=by o-latex] 
      (w1) {$w_1$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[start chain=3]
    \node[on chain=3] at (0,-1.5cm) 
      (x3) {$z_3$};
    \node[on chain=3,label=below:Weights,join=by o-latex] 
      (w3) {$w_3$};
    \end{scope}
    \node[label=above:\parbox{2cm}{\centering Bias \\ $b$}] at (sigma|-w1) (b) {};

    \draw[-latex] (w1) -- (sigma);
    \draw[-latex] (w3) -- (sigma);
    \draw[o-latex] (b) -- (sigma);

    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (x1.north west) -- node[left=10pt] {Inputs} (x3.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

But I haven't been able to modify it to get the result I want. I tried to first of all delete the z_i nodes, but this messes up the entire figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an answer. It's one for you to modify as you want with only basic options of `path` and `node`: change color, adding/removing some node, etc. Please let me know if you can/can't  modify from my code!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\path
(0,0)     node[circle,draw,scale=2,inner sep=2pt] (S) {$\Sigma$}
+(90:2.5) node[circle,draw,inner sep=2.5pt] (b) {}
          node[above=1mm] {$b_1^{(2)}$}
+(-3.5,1.5)  node[circle,fill=green!50]  (x1) {$x_1$}
+(-3.5,0)    node[circle,fill=green!50]  (x2) {$x_2$}
+(-3.5,-1.5) node[circle,fill=green!50]  (x3) {$x_3$}
(2,0)    node[draw] (g) {$g$} node[above=3mm]{Activation}
+(15:3)  node[circle,fill=red!50]  (y1) {$\hat{y}_1$}
+(-15:3) node[circle,fill=red!50]  (y2) {$\hat{y}_2$};
\draw[->] (S)--(g);
\draw[->] (b)--(S);
\draw[->] (g)--(y1) node[pos=.6,above]{$\omega_{1,1}^{(3)}$};
\draw[->] (g)--(y2) node[pos=.6,below]{$\omega_{2,1}^{(3)}$};
\draw[->] (x1)--(S) node[pos=.4,above]{$\omega_{1,1}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x2)--(S) node[pos=.4,above]{$\omega_{1,2}^{(2)}$};
\draw[->] (x3)--(S) node[pos=.4,above]{$\omega_{1,3}^{(2)}$};
\draw[blue] (1,0) circle(2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```